# Build is faling when I'm trying to deploy on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm having trouble getting my application on Heroku, I'm getting the following error, I've already searched around here on Stackoverflow and I've seen responses saying to remove /node_modules and package-lock.json, but unfortunately the error remains.

**Output:**

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
   
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  14.16.1
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
   
   Resolving node version 14.16.1...
   Downloading and installing node 14.16.1...
   Using default npm version: 6.14.12
   
-----> Installing dependencies
   Installing node modules
   
   > nodemon@2.0.15 postinstall /tmp/build_1e107d4a/node_modules/nodemon
   > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
   
   Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
    > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
   
   added 208 packages in 3.879s
   
-----> Build
   Running build
   
   > teste@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_1e107d4a
   > concurrently "cd airbnb/ && npm run build"
   
   [0] 
   [0] > airbnb@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_1e107d4a/airbnb
   [0] > react-scripts build
   [0] 
   [0] sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
   [0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! syscall spawn
   [0] npm ERR! file sh
   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
   [0] npm ERR! airbnb@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
   [0] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
   [0] npm ERR! 
   [0] npm ERR! Failed at the airbnb@0.1.0 build script.
   [0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   [0] 
   [0] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   [0] npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ZNegh/_logs/2021-11-16T19_01_58_803Z-debug.log
   [0] cd airbnb/ && npm run build exited with code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! teste@1.0.0 build: `concurrently "cd airbnb/ && npm run build"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the teste@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ZNegh/_logs/2021-11-16T19_01_58_824Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed
   
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is with react-script, react-scripts is (by default) a **devDependency** for **CRA** apps, **but Heroku Node buildpack** has environment **NODE_ENV=production** which causes npm install to skip devDeps.

To install those devDeps too:

```
npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build
```

## additional information.

Please check in your server-side (if you are using it)/add `Procfile` without any extension in the root directory.

and inside the `Procfile`  add `web: node here your main file name, for example, index.js in my case`.

## Please add your pacacge.js code as well so it helps us to help you better.